# Jquery Selector - To find if a div has innertext

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I found this:

```
$('div:contains("male")')
```

but what i want is if the selector which is a div contains a word at all, how would we achieve this?

So something like:

```
$('div:contains("*").length > 0')
```

```
$(document).on("click", "div:contains(*).length > 0", function (e) {

e.stopPropagation();
$(".hoversel").css("outline", "none");
$(".hoverstamp").removeClass("hoverstamp");
var pHoverSel = $(this).parents(".hoversel")[0];
//$(pHoverSel).removeClass("hoversel");
$(pHoverSel).addClass("hoverstamp");

var sectionId = $(this).closest(".section").attr("id");
var componentData = GetCompnentData(window.parent.componentDataArr, sectionId);
parentCallToPassComponentData(componentData, sectionId);

$("#myfile").click();
});
```

Comment: `td` is for a table cell.  `div` is for a div.  Have you tried `$('div:contains("male"))`? Also, why not provide some sample HTML so we know what you're working with?

Comment: sorry i have edited the question, i want to find all div that contains any word?

Comment: *if the selector which is a div contains a word at all*, then what?

Comment: So... `$('div').innerText.length > 0`?

Comment: then return that element or jquery object

Comment: i need to do it in a jquery selector

Comment: @Marc why `length()` and not `length`?

Comment: @Marc `$('div')` has no `innerText` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides `createPseudo`.  You can select divs which has innerText using custom pseudo selector. In below code snippet, I have created a `:hasText` which selects only divs with word and ignores remaining.

Example selector usage:
 `div:hasText` selects all divs which has any inner text 
 `div:hasText(Human)` selects all divs which has text with `Human`

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ravinila/s4b7ue5f/ 
Reference: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#-backwards-compatible-plugins-for-pseudos-with-arguments

```js
// jQuery custom pseudo selector :hasText
(function($) {
  function has_text(elem, text) {
    var innerText = (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "");
    return (
      (text === undefined && innerText.trim().length > 0) ||
      (innerText.indexOf(text) > -1)
    );
  }

  $.expr.pseudos.hasText = $.expr.createPseudo ?
    $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
      return function(elem) {
        return has_text(elem, text);
      };
    }) :
    function(elem, i, match) {
      return has_text(elem, match[3]);
    };

})(jQuery);


// Sample pseudo selector code 

$(document).on('click', 'div:hasText', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div:hover {
  background: #eaeaff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Div (click me)</div>
<div> Sample words (click me)</div>

<h3>below divs are without a word (ignored)</h3>
<div>        </div>
<div><!-- has comment with a extra space --> </div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no selector for that. You can't use operators like `.length` in a selector.

Use the `filter()` method.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return this.innerText.trim() != "";
})
```

I use `.trim()` so it will not include DIVs that just contain whitespace, they have to include some actual text. If you want blank DIVs as well, remove that.

Comment: OP said he only wanted to know whether the inner text `.length` was higher than 0, so you could probably drop that `trim()` part.

Comment: @JoãoHaas He said "contains a word". I think a DIV with just whitespace probably doesn't count.

Comment: yeah, but the query he described was `contains("*").length > 0`, which would include divs with empty spaces.

Comment: @JoãoHaas It's a common mistake to forget about extraneous whitespace.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain that he can remove that if he wants blank DIVs.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure there's an actual query for this. Given how JQuery queries are done, I believe the overhead of doing the computation in code would not be too big compared to doing a query.